Second existence theorem for weak solution of uniformly elliptic PDE in Evans
I have some questions on the proof of second existence theorem (theorem 4 in section 6.2.3 in Evans' pde book, one could have a copy of this book here). The following is abridged from step 4:

we recall further from D.5 that the dimension of the space $N$
of the solutions of $(21)$ is finite and equals the dimension of the space $N^\ast$
of solutions of
$$v−K^\ast v=0.$$
We readily check however that $(21)$ holds if and only if $u$
is a weak solution of $(11)$ and that $(22)$ holds if and only if $v$
is weak solution of $(12)$.

My question is that how can we transfer the equation $v=K^\ast v$ to the equivalent equation $L^\ast v=0,$ since I don't know how to handle the adjoint of $K$ well. It seems that $K$ should be treated as the composition of $i, \gamma L_{\gamma}^{-1}$ and $i^\ast$ in order to be a linear map between $L^2(U)$ and $L^2(U),$ where $i:H_0^1(U)\to L^2(U)$ is the inclusion map and $i^\ast$ is the adjoint of $i,$ i.e. $K=i\circ \gamma L_\gamma^{-1}\circ i^\ast.$ Then $K^\ast = (i^{\ast})^{\ast}\circ (\gamma L_\gamma^{-1})^{\ast}\circ i^\ast=i\circ (\gamma L_\gamma^{-1})^\ast\circ i^\ast,$ am I right?
